# Encode/Decode Array of SAPOData.EntityValue to CompositeStorage

Tags: ios, swift, sap-cloud-sdk

I'm working with SAP Cloud Platform SDK for iOS, trying to figure out how to put an array of `EntityValue`s into a `CompositeStorage`, and get them out.  I'm getting error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Foundation.(_PlistKey in _5692656F4C05BA2A580AE9322E9FB0A6)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), Foundation.(_PlistKey in _5692656F4C05BA2A580AE9322E9FB0A6)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0))], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found __NSCFData instead.", underlyingError: nil))

I'm trying to get the values from the `CompositeStore` here:

```
var entities: [ExpensereportType] {
    do {
        guard let results = try Cache.shared.store.get(Array<ExpensereportType>.self, for: CollectionType.expensereport.rawValue) else {
            return []
        }
        return results
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        return []
    }
}
```

And they're being encoded here:

```
self.service.fetchReservation(matching: query) { result, error in
    guard let result = result else { return completionHandler(error!) }

    do {
        let encodedResult = try JSONEncoder().encode(result)
        try self.store.put(encodedResult, for: CollectionType.reservation.rawValue)
    }
    catch {
        completionHandler(error)
    }
    completionHandler(nil)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this one is interesting:  it turns out that the `JSONEncoder` is smart enough to handle *either* the `Array<EntityValue>` as-is, or have the individual items be map-encoded.  But, the `JSONDecoder` automatically handles the top-level Array item, and it is up to you to map-decode the items.

Working solution:

```
// MARK: - Encode
self.service.fetchReservation(matching: query) { result, error in
        guard let result = result else {
            completionHandler(error!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let encodedResult = try JSONEncoder().encode(result)
            // try result.map { try JSONEncoder().encode($0) }   ALSO VALID
            try self.store.put(encodedResult, for: CollectionType.expensereport.rawValue)
        }
//...

// MARK: - Decode `Array<ExpensereportType>`
guard let results = try Cache.shared.store.get(Array<ExpensereportType>.self, for: CollectionType.expensereport.rawValue) else {
    return []
}
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo.updateValue(myDataService.metadata, forKey: CSDLDocument.csdlInfoKey)
return try results.map { try decoder.decode(ExpensereportType.self, from: $0)}
```